# Screen Brightness Available to mobile browsers?

Tags: html, dom, browser, mobile-browser

Is the device's brightness level available to the browser?

I found this - http://mzl.la/SSBobX - but I'm not sure that this article is valid anymore as I can't find anything in the screen object or in the settings it refers to.

Is there a cross-browser implementation of this?

Comment: From the two bugs I can find ([707626](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707626) and [729430](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729430)) I get the impression this functionality is only intended to be available on [Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS)

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. Thanks for confirming.